# Is there a way to make PhantomJS (or any headless browser) use an alternate font cache?

Tags: linux, command-line, fonts

Is there a way to make PhantomJS (or any headless browser) use an alternate font cache besides `/usr/share/fonts/`? One way to use more fonts (e.g. CJK fonts) with PhantomJS is to [install them](https://medium.com/@stockholmux/besting-phantomjs-font-problems-ee22795f5c0b#.npebtyx1n) to this directory. However, this is a shared server and cannot be done.

I cannot seem to find a [CLI parameter](http://phantomjs.org/api/command-line.html) for this. Please forgive me if this is a silly question.

This is a RedHat build, and yum and rpm are disabled.

**Screenshot with PhantomJS** - fonts not loading:

[image: Failed font rendering]

**Desired result** (http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/typography/web-fonts/):

[image: Actual fonts rendering]

---

**SOLVED:** @grochmal showed me that fonts can be installed in the home folder. I ran `fc-cache -vf` and the system fonts and the `~/.fonts/TTF` fonts get cached. For example, running `fc-list "impact"` finds the Impact font (*for personal use only*):

```
> fc-list impact
Impact:style=Regular,Normal,obyčejné,Standard,Κανονικά,Normaali,Normál,Normale,Standaard,Normalny,Обычный,Normálne,Navadno,Arrunta
```

I confirmed this with the stack trace cleverly suggested by @grochmal:

```
strace ./phantomjs ../examples/rasterize.js http://example.com img.jpg 2>&1 | grep font
```

and found out that PhantomJS is indeed looking in my user fonts directory

```
open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/verdana.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 11
open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/AndaleMo.TTF", O_RDONLY) = 11
open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/arial.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 11
open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/cour.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 11
open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/georgia.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 11
open("/home/user1/.fonts/TTF/impact.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 11
...
```

Comment: Ops, my rasterize example was poor. You should get a better result with `strace phantomjs rasterize.js http://v1.jontangerine.com/silo/typography/web-fonts/ file.pdf 2>&1 | grep ttf` (i.e. using the browser to rasterize the page itself, although I do not see the `impact` font being used on the page).  Also, your system is using `fontconfig` therefore placing the font in `~/.local/share/fonts/TTF` (I'm assuming it is a TTF font, right?) is safer (and there is no need to use `ttmkfdir` or `mkfontdir` in there.)

Comment: Sorry if this is confusing, the issue is that current *nix has **two** systems to manage fonts `mkfontdir` and `fontconfig`.  Also the `HomemadeApple` output in my answer happened because I forgot to run `fc-cache` so the font was loaded manually (instead of being taken from the cache).

Comment: @grochmal You solved it. This is working for the CLI in a shell. Thank you very much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhantomJS respects `fontconfig` directories and even the old `font.dir`/`font.scale` postscript font configuration.  For example I have and old Type 1 font:

```
$ find ~/.fonts/Type1/
/home/grochmal/.fonts/Type1/
/home/grochmal/.fonts/Type1/augie___.pfb
/home/grochmal/.fonts/Type1/fonts.scale
/home/grochmal/.fonts/Type1/fonts.dir
```

(That was created with the ol' X11 `mkfontdir`)

And, for a better example, I'll copy a `fotnconfig` font into my home directory:

```
$ mkdir -p ~/.local/share/fonts/TTF
$ cp /usr/share/fonts/TTF/HomemadeApple.ttf ~/.local/share/fonts/TTF
$ fc-cache  # just in case
```

Now let's see how PhantomJS uses them (using a classic example from the PhantomJS github):

```
$ wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ariya/phantomjs/master/examples/rasterize.js
```

`strace` prints all system calls (including filesystem access):

```
$ strace phantomjs rasterize.js 2>&1 | grep font | grep grochmal |grep -v cache
stat("/home/grochmal/.config/fontconfig/conf.d", 0x7ffff95fbbc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/grochmal/.config/fontconfig/conf.d", 0x7ffff95fbbc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/grochmal/.config/fontconfig/conf.d", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/grochmal/.config/fontconfig/conf.d", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/grochmal/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf", 0x7ffff95fbbc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/grochmal/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf", 0x7ffff95fbbc0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/grochmal/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/grochmal/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/grochmal/.fonts.conf.d", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/grochmal/.fonts.conf.d", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/grochmal/.fonts.conf", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/home/grochmal/.fonts.conf", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
stat("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
stat("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts/HomemadeApple.ttf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=110080, ...}) = 0
open("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts/HomemadeApple.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 6
stat("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts/TTF", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
stat("/home/grochmal/.fonts", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/home/grochmal/.fonts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
stat("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts/TTF", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts/TTF", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
stat("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts/TTF", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts/TTF", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
open("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts/TTF", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
stat("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts/TTF/HomemadeApple.ttf", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=110080, ...}) = 0
open("/home/grochmal/.local/share/fonts/TTF/HomemadeApple.ttf", O_RDONLY) = 5
stat("/home/grochmal/.fonts/Type1", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
open("/home/grochmal/.fonts/Type1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
```

And PhantomJS went to the font directories and loaded them!

I do not have a `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` which *may* be needed for CJK fonts (because those *may* need some actual configuration), but you can copy a file from `/etc/fonts/conf.d/*` (notably some `nonlatin` font, to get a sample configuration).

Yet, you can probably get away with most fonts by simply dropping them into `~/.local/share/fonts/TTF` and then running `fc-cache`.

Disclaimer: An old RedHat (5 for sure, not sure about 6) may not be using `fontconfig`, that's why I included the PFB font in the example.  In that case you need to use `ttmkfdir` and `mkfontdir` to generate the `font.scale` and `font.dir` files.

References:

- [Arch Linux's extensive article on fontconfig](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/font_configuration)

Comment: You've given me a lot of good information here. Let's me try some of these things and let you know how it goes. ^^

Comment: Your suggestions are helpful, and your effort is appreciated. I've tried to reproduce your results. Would you kindly have a look at my question edit?